# I am stuck at Django undefined main_page

Tags: django

I am learning Django and doing the job of setting everything up.
I have my views.py in jangoTest/first/views.py
in which I defined:

```
def main_page(request):
    output = '''
    <html>
      .....
    </html>
return HttpResponse(output)
```

I have my urls.py in jangoTest/urls.py
in which I wrote:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
urlpatterns = patterns('',(r'^$', main_page),)
```

but the main_page turns out 'undefined' and I am stuck at this point.
Any one knows how to fix this problem???

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should 1. Check if your main_page is called at all. 2. Check what the output actually contains before returning. Printing to log can help do this.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you missing the import in the urls.py file?

```
from views import *
```